# how to programmatically create menu items while creating nodes?

Tags: api, drupal

I'm creating some nodes programmatically, thus:

```
foreach ($titles as $t) {
    $n = new stdClass();
    $n->type = 'myType';
    $n->uid = 1;
    $n->title = $t;
    $menu = array();
    $menu['link_title'] = $t;
    $menu['menu_name'] = 'primary-links';
    // this attempt at placing the menu item in a particular place in the 
    // menu hierarchy didn't work:
    $menu['parent'] = 'primary-links:867';
    $menu['depth'] = 3;
    $menu['p1'] = '580';
    $menu['p2'] = '867';
    $n->menu = $menu;
    node_save($n);
}
```

I've got a menu structure like this:

```
primary-links
    Parent 1
        Child 1
        Child 2
    Parent 2
        Child 3
```

I want the new menu items to appear as children of Child 3. I was able to create menu items at the same time as the nodes, and they appeared in the correct menu, but not in the correct place in the hierarchy. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your over complicating it.  In the past when I've programmatically created menu items for nodes, I just set the menu_name, link_title, and plid (parent link id), ie:

```
$menu['link_title'] = $t;
$menu['menu_name'] = 'primary-links';
$menu['plid'] = 867;
```

The menu module takes over at some point during the call to node_save and does the rest for you.

~Matt

Comment: plid was the part I was missing. Thanks.

Comment: How do you programmatically arrive with `867` without hard-coding it?

Comment: You'd either use 0 for putting the menu item at the top level of the menu, or depending on what you want to set as the parent, you could use node_load() to load the node and check the menu item (you want the mlid from it), or query for it somehow from the menu_links table.  Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

In drupal 7 you need to set also enabled to 1 (see: [menu_node_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!menu!menu.module/function/menu_node_save/7)):

```
$node->menu = array(
  'link_title' => $node->title,
  'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
  'plid' => 0,
  'enabled' => 1,
);
```

Comment: Without "enabled" explicitly set, a new menu item will not be created for the node. +1 for this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Also had to add

> 'description' => ''

to the array otherwise I got an error for Drupal 7