# How can I set the mlid and plid of a node menu link?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm creating several nodes from the install profile, each of which having it's own menu settings.

What I want to happen is to have some of the menu items be the children of some other menu items, hard-coding the `mlid` or `plid` if necessary.

From the code snippet below, all the values reflect in the node when viewed from the Drupal admin and in the database, except for the `mlid` and `parent`. I also tried setting `plid` in place of `parent`, but it also didn't work.

```
$node->menu['link_title'] = 'Some title';
$node->menu['menu_name'] = 'main-menu';
$node->menu['mlid'] = 11000;
$node->menu['parent'] = 10000;
$node->path = array(
  'alias' => 'somealias'
);
node_save($node);
```

How can I force to set the node menu links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the core code of `menu` module, it seems that `enabled` value needs to be part of the `menu item` definition otherwise it doesn't save anything in database (it only delete, based on a given `mlid`).

```
$node->menu = array(
    'link_title' => 'Some title',
    'description' => '', // needs to pass this also or you will get php warnings
    'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
    'mlid' => 361, // needs to be an existing mlid or it will generate a new mlid value
    'plid' => 299, // needs to be an existing foreign mlid id
    'enabled' => 1,
);

node_save($node);
```

Answer (score -1):

You probably will need to set this up as a second step.

First create & save your nodes.
 
After your nodes are saved, you should have the path for each node.

At that point you should use

```
hook_menu
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7

You probably won't have to worry about hardcoding the values for mlid & plid, simply settings the link_path value should create your menu structure

```
 function mymodule_menu() {
    $items['abc/def'] = array(
      'page callback' => 'mymodule_abc_view',
    );

    $items['abc/def/ghi'] = array(
      'page callback' => 'mymodule_abc_view',
    );

    $items['abc/def/lmn'] = array(
      'page callback' => 'mymodule_abc_view',
    );

    $items['abc/def/opq'] = array(
      'page callback' => 'mymodule_abc_view',
    );

    etc...

    return $items;
  }
```

You could also have a look at

```
menu_link_save
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_link_save/7

Comment: Bearing in mind that Drupal is a CMS, and not a static HTML template, you want to keep things flexible. Hardcoding the values as m4olivei suggest is a pretty bad approach, your code will not be portable and some changes may simply break your menu structure. Of course it will work in the short term, but hardcoding values is really a no no in programming. Please read the docs about the Menu system on drupal.org and you will learn how the best practice is to use hook_menu.

Comment: It depends on what you're doing.  If you're just importing some nodes as a one time operation, then it's fine to hard code the parent menu item.

Comment: The OP mentions an install profile, this kind of implies that this is not a one time operation.

Answer (score -1):

I answered a very similar question here:

[how to programmatically create menu items while creating nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603289/how-to-programmatically-create-menu-items-while-creating-nodes/2609138#2609138)

Try that, see if it works.